# Which approach to follow if I want to modify the built-in Issue Status Choices?

Tags: list, development, content-type, site-column, issue-tracking

I have created an issue tracking tool, which come with built-in “Issue Status” field with the following built-in choices ; Active , Resolved & closed. Now I want to have different choices (open, in progress, closed & pending) for my issue tracking list. So there seems to be multiple approaches to do so, such as:-

1. Modify the built-in "Issue Status" site column at the site collection level ,and modify the choices to my new values.
2. Modify the built-in "Issue Status" column at the list level, while keep it as is in the site collection level.
3. Create a new site column named “Custom Status” and keep the built-in column unmodified. Then add the new custom site column to the “Issue” content type at site collection level.
4. Create a new list column (not site column) named “Custom Status” and add it to the list content type (not to the site content type).
5. Create a new site column named “Custom Status” but add it to the list content type.

So can anyone advice which approach I need to follow?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the Issue Status field does not meet your requirement you should not use it and use a custom column instead.

If you envision this list being used in multiple places and across site collections I'd suggest using a Managed Metadata field, because once your users start using it they will find they need additional choices.

Comment: but is it wrong if i modify the Issue Status field choices at the list level,, as SP supports this scenario. where the choices for the Issue Status fields at the list level is now different from the choices at the site collection level... is this wrong ?

Comment: but using the managed meta data will add extra work, as sub-sites admin will need to create a new term set and then associate the site column with the new term set, while using a drop down list sub site admin can modify the column and add the required choices ?? what do u think ?

Comment: You are correct, if the choices need to be customizable per instance then the term set makes less sense.